# glxtest: libpci missing although I made an apt install

Tags: apt, 20.04

I would like to run Gecko driver but I get an error glxtest: libpci missing. I made `apt install libpci-dev` so it is the newest version, then restart server. But if I try to run Geckodriver I have the same error again.

```
1619470825979   geckodriver     INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:29905
1619470826561   mozrunner::runner       INFO    Running command: "/snap/bin/firefox" "--marionette" "-headless" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "/tmp/rust_mozprofileOXAgmN"
*** You are running in headless mode.
[GFX1-]: glxtest: libpci missing
[GFX1-]: glxtest: libEGL initialize failed
[GFX1-]: glxtest: Unable to open a connection to the X server
[GFX1-]: glxtest: libEGL initialize failed
[GFX1-]: No GPUs detected via PCI
```

Driver runs as Selenium test case. Here is Java code with driver settings:

```
public static void setDriver()
{
    String browser = System.getProperty("browser");
    browser = browser == null || browser.equals("") ? CHROME : browser.toLowerCase();

    Configuration.remote = HUB_URL;
    Configuration.browser = browser;
    Configuration.headless = conf.getBoolean("env.production");
}
```

How can I fix it? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove Snap version of Firefox by

```
snap remove firefox
```

and then use Firefox from the repository

```
sudo apt-get install firefox
sudo apt-get install firefox-geckodriver
```

---

If you need newer firefox - check packages from Mozilla PPAs - [*firefox-next*](https://launchpad.net/%7Emozillateam/+archive/ubuntu/firefox-next) or [*daily*](https://launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-mozilla-daily/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) .

Comment: Yes that first line it is gone. Now error starts on second glxtest: libEGL initialize failed. Does it matter?

Comment: It depends. How do you run geckodriver? Do you have GUI on the machine with geckodriver installed? If you are using some script, please add it to the question.

Comment: I added the code. It seems tests run successfully although there still the same missing warning. I don't know what it means.